# Службы и протоколы

Tags: клиент-сервер, терминология, сетевое-программирование

Можно ли сказать, что служба - это интерфейс, а протокол - это реализация, излагаясь терминами ООП

Comment: Ровно наоборот. Протокол описывает интерфейс взаимодействия, и этот протокол могут реализовывать много разных служб-реализаций

Comment: @andreymal странно, вот, что пишет Таненбаум в своей книге: "Стоит провести аналогию с языками программирования. Службу можно уподобить 
абстрактному типу данных или объекту в объектно-ориентированных языках про-
граммирования. Он определяет операции, которые могут выполняться с объектом, 
но не описывает, как реализованы эти операции. В этом случае протокол, напротив, 
относится к реализации службы и, таким образом, невидим для пользователей службы.".

Comment: контекст нужен и смотря с какого уровня абстракции смотрим. Вам автор пишет "в этом случае", вот в частном случае его примера может быть и так. Но вы то спросили про "в целом". Вот как раз в целом, в общем, протокол - это набор правил взаимодействия, контракт. Это как раз и будет определением интерфейса. Но не надо частное объяснение автора привязывать вообще ко всему.

Comment: Так и написано: Телевизору все равно кто произвел кабель питания. Служба имеет "вход" и "выход". Передача данных на вход и выход определяется протоколом = интерфейс.

Comment: @teran Спасибо за помощь, буду рад, если кто-то составит ответ, который я смогу отметить, как правильный.

Comment: @kaylil_01 Таненбаум под словом «служба» имеет в виду совсем не то, что имел в виду я и плюсанувшие мой коммент, а вы в вопросе забыли уточнить, какой именно смысл вкладывается в слово «служба»

Comment: Если я правильно понял книжку, Таненбаум под словом «служба» имеет в виду нечто, что позволяет организовать передачу данных и предоставляет для этого какой-то интерфейс (например, набор функций listen, connect, accept, receive, send, disconnect), и таком случае действительно протокол (например TCP) будет являться реализацией такой службы. Но лично мне такая терминология кажется странной, я её в живой природе доселе не встречал